# Connecting to remote mySQL via Excel VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, connection-string

Likely a dumb question but brain isn't piecing this together---

**tl;dr:** My main question is how do I choose the right parameters for my connection string?  How do I determine what my driver should be?  Provider?  Option?  Where do I find a list of acceptable parameters?  How do I choose between ADO and OLE?

**Objective:** to connect to a hosted mySQL db of which I am admin.

**Problem:** creating a successful connection string / choosing the right parameters.

I'm new to referencing remote databases.  Been looking all day today and yesterday; there are tons of articles and posts out there but nothing is working for me--I'm just trying to replicate what I see being done when I need to just design the string properly, but I don't know where to start.

I've tried using ActiveX Data Objects 2.7, 2.8 and 6.1 libraries.  Also tried using OLE DB Simple Provider 1.5 Library.  Below tests are using ADO 6.1.

**Tried these connection strings:**

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=ipaddress;PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATABASE=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;
```

**---Error:** waits ~30 seconds, times out and says Invalid Connection String Attribute

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=ipaddress;PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATABASE=db_name;USER=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx;
```

**---Error:** immediately errors and says cannot find installable ISAM

```
SERVER=ipaddress;PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATABASE=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;
```

**---Error:** waits ~30 seconds, times out and says SQL Database does not exist or access denied

I'm sure i've added the correct user with password and permissions.  I haven't done anything with DSN.

I'm on win8.1 x64 using Excel 2013.  Any advice is much appreciated!!

Comment: Don't mix DRIVER & PROVIDER. http://www.connectionstrings.com is a good reference.